# how to simplify jquery animation function code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two function to make some animation efect , how to shorthand this function and change it to simple code ?

```
   $('.box-1').hover(function() {
    $('.box-1').stop().animate({bottom:'0'});
    $('.dul-1').stop().animate({top:'0px'});
},
function() {
  $('.box-1').stop().animate({bottom:'-100px'});
  $('.dul-1').stop().animate({top:'-100px'});
   });

$('.box-2').hover(function() {
    $('.box-2').stop().animate({bottom:'0'});
    $('.dul-2').stop().animate({top:'0px'});
},
function() {
  $('.box-2').stop().animate({bottom:'-100px'});
  $('.dul-2').stop().animate({top:'-100px'});
   });
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9xlog/h3h2kyw4/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check my updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/h3h2kyw4/3/) .add data-index attribute to .box div. so when hover event call script will get index using $(this).attr('data-index');.

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dul-1"></div>
  <div class="dul-2"></div>
  <div class="box box-1" data-index="1"></div>
  <div class="box box-2" data-index="2"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
    index = $(this).attr('data-index');
    $('.box-'+index).stop().animate({bottom:'0'});
    $('.dul-'+index).stop().animate({top:'0px'});
 },
 function() {
    $('.box-'+index).stop().animate({bottom:'-100px'});
    $('.dul-'+index).stop().animate({top:'-100px'});
   }
 );
```

Comment: You can use `$(this).data('index')`

Comment: @Satpal user can take any attribute name :)

Comment: @Satpal yes but i face many problem when use .data() so i always suggest to use .attr().